# How to provision "Content types" in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, provisioning, addfieldasxml

**Short version**
How do I provision Content Types and Site defs in Sharepoint online, onto my host web? I would prefer reusing existing content type definitions

**Long version**

We are migrating a fairly large SP2013 -> SP Online (Provider Hosted)

The part I'm working with is the provisioning, I've been looking at the [pnp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/site-provisioning-sharepoint-add-in)
and they seem to recommend NOT using Feature-provisoning, but they give no reason to why.

Does anyone know why?

- I want to re-use all content type definitions. So I was thinking about copy pasting them to my appweb-project, then somehow getting them to the host-web and provisioning them there, where I want them.
- The alternative would be to keep them as loose xml-files in my provider web, use AddFieldAsXml(), using parts of the xml...but it seems hacky.

I would much rather do the first alternative.